# Linux configuration -- ssmtp: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587

Tags: linux, gmail, mailx, ssmtp

Hi I have RHEL5 with ssmtp installed on it ssmtp-2.61-22.el5.i386.rpm

my /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf updated as below :-

```
AuthUser=mymail@gmail.com
AuthPass=mypassword
FromLineOverride=YES
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
UseSTARTTLS=YES
UseTLS=Yes
RewriteDomain=gmail.com
```

also revaliases updated as below :

```
root:mymail@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
```

i have shutdown sendmail service

when i try to send email with ssmtp i get below error

```
[root@ctmtest ssmtp]# echo "test" | ssmtp -vvv mymail@gmail.com
[<-] 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP v26sm42795996pfi.56 - gsmtp
[->] EHLO ctmtest
[<-] 250 SMTPUTF8
[->] STARTTLS
[<-] 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
ssmtp: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
```

i searched lots of tag with this error , but unable to fix this

my system is able to connect smtp.gmail.com on port 587

```
[root@ctmtest ssmtp]# telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Trying 74.125.200.108...
Connected to smtp.gmail.com (74.125.200.108).
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP o90sm11695907pfi.17 - gsmtp
```

is there anyone who have fixed this ? please suggest

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: The answers below are correct, but I encountered this issue due to a network problem. The fix is documented here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62062113/4196261

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. The following steps worked for me:

1. sudo vi /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
   Add the following:

`TLS_CA_FILE=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
    root=XXXX@gmail.com
    mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
    AuthUser=XXXX
    AuthPass=XYXYX
    UseSTARTTLS=Yes
    UseTLS=Yes
    hostname=AAAA`

Replace:
XXXX- username(mail)
XYXYX- password(mail password)
AAAA- hostname(get by running $hostname)

2. sudo vi /etc/ssmtp/revaliases
   Add the following:

`root:XXXX@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587`

Replace :
XXXX - username(mail)

3. Try running the mail now:

   `$mail -s "adasdas" XXXX@gmail.com`

   CC:
   XYZLoremIpsum
   .
   **'ctrl+D'**

It solved my problem.
Hopefully for a system(Office) you need to configure correct proxy settings otherwise you will get an error:

> cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status

Comment: This solved my problem too; in particular, I had to add a `TLS_CA_FILE=/usr/share/ncat/ca-bundle.crt` line on my Arch Linux system after outgoing mail stopped working recently.

Comment: Is there a `mail` package on RHEL? There isn't one on CentOS. Not version 7, anyway.

Comment: The `mail` package is installed with `yum install mailx`

Comment: Ran into the same problem, except sending via SES at AWS.  The `TLS_CA_FILE` line also solved it for me.

Comment: Thanks for you time, thanks. God is here.

Comment: In artix I had to use `TLS_CA_FILE=/usr/share/kf5/kssl/ca-bundle.crt`

Comment: Also note, unexpected: you will get the "Cannot open <hostname>" error if the TLS_CA_FILE does not exist or if you do not have read permission on this file.

Comment: First remember that AuthPass is a Google App password, not your email password. Second, I fixed it myself I fixed it by changing my hostname to hostname=localhost instead of  hostname:emailaddress@gmail.com

Answer (score 5):

try changing this option

Allowing less secure apps to access your account

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Answer (score 4):

This is perhaps because you're not setting the `hostname` parameter of `ssmtp.conf`. It [should be](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.5) a resolvable, fully-qualified domain name; yours is defaulting to the machine name of `ctmtest` (as shown in the `EHLO` command that you quote above).

The issue that user963 [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35405525/99667) in their answer may also be in action here, but in that case you'll get a different error message, something like `ssmtp: Authorization failed (534 5.7.14 ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment on Haider Raza's answer, but I am short of 1 rep point to comment lol.

From https://superuser.com/questions/431539/special-characters-in-ssmtp-password

ssmtp has bugs parsing passwords containing '=', ':' or '#'. You can use the following workaround:

feed the password directly in the command line argument

ssmtp -ap "Hash#Password" ...

alternatively put the password in an environment variable.

ssmtp -ap $PASSWD ...

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

first to get your hostname type in terminal : hostname

copy it and past in hostname parameter in ssmtp.conf

Answer (score 0):

On my Gentoo Linux system, the error `ssmtp: Cannot open smtp.server.com:port` was caused by an ownership/permissions issue: the file `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` should belong to the group `ssmtp`, which it didn't (and any user allowed to access ssmtp should be a member of that group).

Answer (score 0):

I ws looking for a solution for cacti smtp mail sender. 
And found myself actually sending an email using the postfix service .
I also used localhost in the postfix config.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is my config for outlook365.com that works on Centos 6.10 (Final) - replace all [square brackets] with your own settings:

/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf

```
root=[admin_emailemail@domain.ext]
mailhub=smtp.office365.com:587
RewriteDomain=[domain.ext]
# to find out run hostname command in shell
Hostname=[hostname_or_domain]
AuthUser=[your_smtp_authentication_mailbox@domain.ext]
AuthPass=[your_password]
AuthMethod=LOGIN
FromLineOverride=YES
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
# Use SSL/TLS certificate to authenticate against smtp host.
# When enabled it was failing to send emails
#UseTLSCert=YES
TLS_CA_File=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

/etc/ssmtp/revaliases

```
root:[your_sender_or_authentication_mailbox@domain.ext]:smtp.office365.com:587
```

Answer (score -2):

**Mail functions are all highly broken**, so are the numerous tutorials on the internet.

This is pretty bad, for something that **MUST be EASY for BEGINNERS**.

A little panels of unclear errors you will face:

```
mailx: unrecognized option '-d'
 
mailx: unrecognized option '-v'

s-nail: Setting up PseudoRandomNumberGenerator: *SSL RAND_*
s-nail: New-style URL used without *v15-compat* being set
/home/you/dead.letter 3/106
s-nail: ... message not sent
 
s-nail: Connecting to XX.XX.XX.XXX:465 ... connected.
s-nail: SMTP: Resource temporarily unavailable

s-nail: Obsoletion warning: Use of old-style credentials, which will vanish in v15!

s-nail: Obsoletion warning: please don't use *smtp*: assign a smtp:// URL to *mta*!
 
s-nail: Unexpected EOF on SMTP connection
```

---

No, there is no needs of any credentials to send a simple mail.

**STEP 1**: Install mail-utils

```
sudo apt install mailutils
```

**STEP 2**: Install mutt

```
sudo apt install mutt
```

**STEP 3**: Run the postfix setup

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

Usage press TAB to select OK

[image]

Select "Internet site"

[image]

Enter your domain, or whatever

[image]

Leave all other settings as default. (Press RETURN till the end)

Mails will then be sent from this email: **yourCurrentsession@whatever.com**

**STEP 4**: Apply settings

```
service postfix reload
```

**STEP 5**: Send email

```
echo "Hello world"  | mutt -s "Message sent at $(date)" recipient@gmail.com -y
```

**STEP 6: Optional**. Change sender email and name. Create a .muttrc file in the home folder.

```
echo -e "set from =  \"aname@something.net\"\nset realname = \"Yay\"" > ~/.muttrc
```

Comment: Im so confused by your answer.... how does this relate to `ssmtp` at all