# Unable to connect to mail.google.com on motion configuration

Tags: raspberry-pi, ssmtp

I have set up a motion detection camera on my raspberry pi zero w, and it's able to record videos and save pictures and upload them to dropbox but not sending email notifications on_event_start and this is how I defined my on_event_start (on_event_start echo "email body" | mail -s "subject" myEmail@gmail.com). I'm using ssmtp and mailutils for email packages. Although I'm able to send emails through terminal. This is how my ssmtp.conf looks like:

```
root=postmaster
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
hostname=raspberrypi
AuthUser=myEmail@gmail.com
AuthPass=***********
FromLineOverride=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
UseTLS=YES
RewriteDomain=gmail.com
```

And this is how my revaliases looks like:

```
root:myEmail@gmail:mail.google.com:587
```

This is the error that is logged onto the mail.log when motion is detected by the camera.

```
Unable to connect to "mail.google.com" port 587.
Cannot open mail.google.com:587
```

Is there something that i'm missing or is there any other way to send an email notification when motion is detected? Someone please help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux configuration -- ssmtp: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35130119/linux-configuration-ssmtp-cannot-open-smtp-gmail-com587)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your revaliases file should be pointing to smtp.gmail.com instead of mail.gmail.com. Please try with following in your revaliases file:

root:MyEmailAddress@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, it works perfectly fine. Much appreciated

Comment: Hi @LamolaRabogale, could you please upvote the answer if it fixed your issue?